# Thunderbird not loading email accounts from profile after reinstall

Tags: 20.04, thunderbird

Last week, a botched attempt by my IT helpdesk to fix a problem unrelated to email forced me to re-image my machine.  Before I did that, I made a full backup of my home directory, which I subsequently restored.  However, when I load Thunderbird, it does not recognize my configured email account.  There is no error message, no prompt to set up an account, or anything like that; I just get a view showing only "local folders".

- I've confirmed that I only have one profile in `~/.thunderbird`.
- If I run `thunderbird --ProfileManager`, it lists and allows me to select that profile.
- On load, Thunderbird prompts me for my "primary password", which it appears to recognize, implying that it recognizes at least part of my profile.
- "Collected Addresses" lists a large number of my contacts, again suggesting that it recognizes at least part of my profile.
- grepping for my mail server name within my profile returns a number of hits, implying that I backed up and restored the right profile (as opposed to my old install using a profile stored someplace other than `~/.thunderbird`.

Any idea how I can recover here?  The data appears to still be in my profile; Thunderbird is just refusing to use it.

Answer (score 0):

*BEWARE: This is from memory, I hope I remember correctly*

1. Move away your saved data from `~/.thunderbird/`
2. start Thunderbird
3. create ONE fake email account
4. stop Thunderbird
5. REMOVE the folder named similar to `m85fenct.default` from `~/.thunderbird/`
6. COPY your saved .thunderbird folder CONTENT into `~/.thunderbird/`
7. restart Thunderbird - your data should now be present.